# GCP Oslogin error

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I have enabled os-login for an instance by setting the metadata value as 'enable-oslogin=TRUE'. Even after setting the IAM roles as **Organization admin** and **Owner** of the project the issue persists as shown in the link [GCP ssh error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JT7Kq.png.).

Please guide me to solve the issue.

**Note: I have set all the necessary os-login roles as per the documentation**

Roles I have set for the user: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser, roles/compute.osAdminLogin

Answer (score 0):

The public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access) for OS Login would be helpful. If the user who is trying to do OS login is an external user (not part of the organization), then the user needs the following role along with the other necessary roles:

roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser